# How can I wirte Mathematica code in microsoft word

Tags: code

What I am trying to do is write Mathematica code in Microsoft word because I am doing like tutorial, so how can I insert code with the form in the picture.

[image]

As an alternative what I am doing is to copy the cell in Mathematica as a meta file but the In and Out cells do not have the corresponding numeration. What I get is this. Also I have tried to make snapshot but it looks really bad. Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: I would recommend using Latex instead of word, and using the nice formayting for Mathematica in it as shown here [fanciest-way-to-include-mathematica-code-in-latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84748/fanciest-way-to-include-mathematica-code-in-latex). If you want to use Word, then your best choice is to use images and put them in word. But I would never use Word to make reports myself when Latex is there.

Comment: I'm afraid I also don't have any magical way of including code in Word aside from copying images. Have you considered the advantages of writing a tutorial as a Mathematica notebook? I'll admit that the formatting isn't as nice as Word or Latex, but you can include all kinds of formatted text, equations, and code in a Mathematica notebook. This has the advantage of allowing anyone reading the tutorial to immediately evaluate the code themselves, as well as tweak the code slightly to see what happens. This sort of learning has by far been the most helpful for me, though it may not be for others.

Comment: Yes you can do this on a Mac through Services. You should be able to find out how somewhere on the Wolfram website. Last time I ever did this was probably 8-10 years ago but it worked fine, except that embedded graphics generated from code had a poor resolution.